# Как починить проект?

Tags: java, android

Вот я тут экспериментировал с `git` и вроде ничего особенного не сделал, переключался с ветки на ветку и единственное что это удалил командой

```
git rm --cached .idea/misc.xml
```

потом открыл студию, а так такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как это исправить и вообще в чем проблема... Студия как будто вообще не понимает, что это проект и открывает как набор файлов...

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Попробуй сделать экспорт этого проекта, мне кажется что удалился служебный файл который отвечал за андроид структуру. А вообще папку .idea лучше не трогать и не комитить)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Android Studio есть собственная локальная история:

1) [Правой кнопкой по папке с вашим проектом](http://i7.5cm.ru/i/qqIc.png)

2)[Local History -> Show History](http://i7.5cm.ru/i/mcvq.png)

Затем смотрите изменения, если повезло то папка с предыдущими состояниями проекта цела, и можете сделать revert.

Comment: Очень странно как то получилось, 2 раза перезагружал проект ничего не работало... Перезагрузил ноут открыл и все заработало... Но в целом ваш вариант я думаю сработал бы. Спасибо!